# Routing with rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I just upgraded a rails 3.0.9 application to rails 3.2.1 by watching the railscasts for upgrading to rails 3.1.0 and then 3.2.0.  Before the update my (then working) routes.rb file looked like:

```
match "home" => "pages#index"
match "*page" => "pages#show" 
root :to => "pages#index"
```

After the update I changed my routes.rb file to:

```
match "home" => "pages#index"
match "pages/*page" => "pages#show", :format => false 
root :to => "pages#index"
```

I got this idea from [Ruby on Rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) in the Rout Globbing section, in order to mimic rails version 3.0.x.

Now when I click on my link, rendered by:

```
<li><%= link_to "What We Do", "/what-we-do" %></li>
```

I get this error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/what-we-do"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

rake routes produces:

    home  /home(.:format) pages#index
          /pages/*page    pages#show
    root  /               pages#index
If that is helpful.
```

The page I am trying to render is called what-we-do.html.erb and is located in app/views/pages.

and this is my controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    render :home, :layout => false
  end

  def show
    render static_page 
  rescue 
    # page_not_found
  end


  private

  def static_page
    "#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/views/pages/#{params[:page]}.html.erb"
  end

  def page_not_found
    render "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :layout => false 
  end

end
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: So I figured it out.  I switched my route back to: `match "*page" => "pages#show"` but the real problem was in my controller.  In rails 3.0.X you use RAILS_ROOT but in 3.1 and up it is Rails.root.  Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A member route will require an ID, because it acts on a member. A collection route doesn't because it acts on a collection of objects.

```
map.resources :users, :collection => { :customers_list=> :get }

map.resources :users, :member => { :inactive=> :post }
```

It is treated as `/users/1;inactive=> [:action => 'inactive', :id => 1]`

Answer (score 2):

You have a route that would match `/pages/what-we-do`:

```
/pages/*page    pages#show
```

but there's nothing that would match a URL that doesn't begin with `/pages/` (except `/home` of course). You still need your top-level globbed route:

```
match "*page" => "pages#show"
```

if you want to match `/what-we-do`. Perhaps you misunderstood [this from the routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing):

> Starting from Rails 3.1, wildcard routes will always match the optional format segment by default. For example if you have this route:
>
> ```
> match '*pages' => 'pages#show'
> ```
>
> By requesting `"/foo/bar.json"`, your `params[:pages]` will be equals to `"foo/bar"` with the request format of JSON.

The change is that you don't have to deal with the format handling yourself, it is now automatically handled just like it is for all the other routes.

Answer (score 1):

routes needs to be like this -

```
match "home", :to => "pages#index"
root :to => "pages#index"
match ":page", :to => "pages#show"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like You didn't mentioned the intended action in the routes . if your using a static route inside any scaffolding you should mention that action in routes inside

```
collection :controller do 
  get 'action name'
end
```